# Find a basis of $V = \mathcal{P}_2(R)$ given the matrix of the linear transformation $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I have that $V = \mathcal{P}_2(R)$ and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ where $T$ is defined by $T(p) = xp', p \in V.$

In a previous problem, I found that the matrix for $T$ $w.r.t.$ the basis $1, x, x^2$ is
$$M(T) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}.$$

I am given the matrix for $T$ with respect to an unknown basis (which is the same for the domain and codomain). The matrix is
$$M'(T) = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & -3 & 6\\
0 & 1 & 4\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

**I must find a basis of $V$ such that it satisfies the matrix $M'(T)$.**

I tried approaching this problem by solving systems of equations for the three elements of the unknown basis, but I got stuck on how to apply this to $M'(T)$. Also, I was unable to solve the system of unknowns as I assumed each element of the basis was of the form $ax^2+bx+c$, where $a,b,c\in F$.

How should I approach this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use eigen decomposition.

The characteristic polynomial for $M'$ is

$p(t) = (2-t)(1-t)t$.

The characteristic values are $\lambda = 0, 1, 2$.

Now find the basis of null space of $M', M'-I, M'-2I$.

Those are

$
\begin{bmatrix}
9 \\
4 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
$,
$
\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$,
$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$

corresponding to $\lambda=0,1,2$.

Now M' =

$
\begin{bmatrix}
    9       & 3 & 1  \\
    4       & 1 &   \\
    -1      &  &  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0       &  &   \\
         & 1 &   \\
       &  &  2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    9       & 3 & 1  \\
    4       & 1 &   \\
    -1      &  &  
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$.

Now denote the old basis as $v_1=1,v_2=x, v_3=x^2$ and new basis for $M'$ as $w_1, w_2, w_3$. Then $(v_1, v_2, v_3)=(w_1, w_2, w_3)
\begin{bmatrix}
    9       & 3 & 1  \\
    4       & 1 &   \\
    -1      &  &  
\end{bmatrix}$.

$w_1 = v_3, 3w_1+1w_2 = v_2, 9w_3+4w_1-w_3=v1$.

Can you proceed from here?

(answer: $w_1 = x^2, w_2=x-3x^2, w_3=-1+4x-3x^2$)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. Unfortunately, we haven't covered eigen decomposition so I would be afraid to use it as a method of solving. Is there another way I can approach this problem, perhaps by using the standard basis $1, x, x^2$ and the matrix $M'(T)$?